# How to add special character i-umlaut in R Quarto?

Tags: utf-8, r-markdown, special-characters, quarto

I am preparing a textbook using Quarto. I have a problem changing the author name. This is what is written:

```
project:
  type: book

book:
  title: "biostatistics"
  author: "Sa\"{i}d M"
  date: "10/7/2023"
  chapters:
    - index.qmd
    - intro.qmd
    - summary.qmd
    - references.qmd

bibliography: references.bib

format:
  html:
    theme: cosmo
  pdf:
    documentclass: scrreprt

editor: visual
```

As you know, `Sa\"{i}d` should yield **Saïd**. But in Quarto it yields this instead:

[image]

Can someone tell me where is the problem? What do I need to change? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Use `Sa&iuml;d` or `Sa&#xEF;d` or `Sa&#239;d` instead of `Sa\"{i}d`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add special characters like *Latin Small Letter I with Diaeresis* like this (in visual editor use [Insert + Special Characters](https://quarto.org/docs/visual-editor/content.html#unicode-symbols)). Works both in HTML and PDF:

```
---
title: Untitled
format: pdf
author: "Saïd M"
---
```

[image]